# Can I force certain keys in a map to have certain types in scala?

Tags: scala, refinement-type

For example, I know that at runtime I will have only the following keys: `string-key-1`, `number-key-1`.

I can create a map of key to typed value like this:

```
sealed trait Container {
  type T

  def resolve: T = this match {
    case StringContainer(s) => s.asInstanceOf[String]
    case BigDecimalContainer(n) => n.asInstanceOf[BigDecimal]
    // and more
  }
}


final case class StringContainter(v: String) { type T = String } 
final case class BigDecimalContainer(v: BigDecimal) { type T = BigDecimal }
```

Then I could enforce types like this:

```
Map[String, Container]
```

But that still requires the client to know that a `string-key-1` type cannot map to a `BigDecimalContainer`. Is there any way to create logic that internally maps tuples of `(key, container type) => value`? Some sort of implicit predicate function is probably what I need, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [shapless hmap](https://www.scala-exercises.org/shapeless/HMap):

```
class KeyToValue[K, V]
case class StringKey(key: String)
case class IntKey(key: String)
implicit val keyToString = new KeyToValue[StringKey, String]
implicit val keyToInt = new KeyToValue[IntKey, Int]

val map = HMap[KeyToValue](
    StringKey("string-key") -> "string-value",
    IntKey("int-key") -> 0
)

val stringValueOption = map.get(StringKey("string-key")) //will be Some("string-value")
val intValueOption = map.get(IntKey("int-key")) //will be Some(0)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is what I'm looking for. Might be related but I [opened up another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56346066/add-or-modify-values-in-a-shapeless-hmap) on how to add/modify keys in an HMap. I think I might need to use Lens?