# Add or modify values in a shapeless HMap

Tags: scala, shapeless, lenses

Does anyone know how I might add or modify values in a shapeless HMap? The only functions I see on the HMap definition are:

- `get`
- `+` (which looks like it's creating a new map and adding the `(k,v)` tuple)
- `-` (same as above)

My suspicion is that I will need to use lens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shapeless.HMap` is immutable. It's a wrapper (with type-level enhancements) of `scala.collection.immutable.Map`.

`+` adds or modifies a pair (returning new HMap).

Lenses also create a copy. Immutability/persistence is typical for FP.

Comment: Fine. That would require me to create my own function for adding an item to an HMap, no?

Comment: @franklin Why can't you use standard `+`?

Comment: I'm having trouble writing the "evidences" that will allow me to add heterogenous types to the map. I guess it has nothing to do with usage of the standard `+`.